# Obfuscate IDs [pages, users ...] with a static number of digits

Tags: php

I was searching for a way to obfuscate the IDs that are show to the end user. But with a static number of digits `Like the md5() function`, with the ability of reversing back to the original ID.

`e.x: 1         => N9VRD7QB4SG2`
`e.x: 999999999 => RC401BALV74W`

Comment: why would you wish to do this? does not add to security

Comment: @EdHeal It is not about security at all. It is JUST a policy of the company that I am working on their application -_-.

Comment: exclusive or will do the trick.

Comment: Create another entity attribute (a column in DB or whatever you use as a persistent storage) where you put some unique randomly generated string and use it as a public identifier instead

Comment: @EdHeal Sorry, I didn't get what you mean! Anyway, will you help me on this or ...?

Comment: @Dazents: it's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. If you just add `1000000` to an `id` which will result in `1000001` (for `id=1`) will it be enough level of obfuscation? If not - what's wrong with it? The better if you provide the **exact** requirement from that company.

Comment: @Dazents - read about xor. but why? seems awaste of time not to achieve anything?

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, but I wish if this could be done without having to make a MySQL query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
id = oldid ^ 0xfedad1234;
```

Coded

now

```
oldid = id ^ 0xfedad1234;
```

Back to the original

No SQL involved

Comment: Nice and simple solution for a rather weird problem. +1

Comment: Why the four and a half octets, though? :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest solution is to use the first N chars from a hash of the original ID (plus a salt) and storing the association on a database table:

```
hash_id | original_id
```

You can choose a hashing algorithm following these advices: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

EDIT: as zerkms wrote, you want to add a UNIQUE index on the hash_id column in order to avoid colliding hashes.

Comment: 1. From a hash of *what*? 2. How is it related to passwords?

Comment: Hash of the original ID (plus a salt)

Comment: why to derive on an ID if even a random number would suit? And what salt is for in this case?

Comment: It's related to passwords in the sense that the hash represents a value that you don't want to share publicly.

Comment: Well, you can use a random number. I usually use the ID because it guarantees uniqueness (considering the original ID is unique).

Comment: "I usually use the ID because it garantees uniqueness" --- applying hash to a salted id **DOES NOT** guarantee uniqueness

Comment: The salt is just a random string you append to the id before hashing it, to make it harder for people to guess which ID the hash represents.

Comment: unfortunately your knowledge about why passwords are hashed and salted is a bit messy, sorry.

Comment: @zerkms you're right, we can have coliding hashes, but the probabily of that happening is smaller than using a random generator (right?).. I don't think you can ACTUALLY guarantee uniqueness (of course you can check existing hashes, etc.)

Comment: @zerkms no problem, you can complement the answer

Comment: "I don't think you can ACTUALLY guarantee uniqueness" --- you easily can. Just create `UNIQUE` constraint for a column and use *random* hashes

Comment: @zerkms exactly, that's an extra step you sure want to take

Comment: it's an extra step that *guarantees* you will always have *consistent data*.